# touch screen monitor windows forms app c#

Tags: c#, winforms, touch, screen, monitor

I've this application which shows information from a website to user who comes to my shop. It works perfectly but now I've touch screen monitor so I would like to enable it. Can I change this code or I'll have to built another app from scratch?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebsiteWrapper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Timer IdleTimer = new Timer();
        const int Tempo = 90000; // 1min - represents the configured time to see if the application is in idle
        public Form1()
        {

            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            IdleTimer.Interval = Tempo;
            IdleTimer.Tick += TimesUp;
            IdleTimer.Start();
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);

        }

        //avoid the page to open external links
        private void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IdleTimer.Enabled)
            {
                IdleTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        //reload de webBrowser when it reachs 1min of inactivity
        public void TimesUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.myWebsite.co.mz/index.php/pt/novo");

        }
    }

    //events messages 
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public class LeaveIdleMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2;
        const int WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A4;
        const int WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5;
        const int WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A7;
        const int WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00A8;
        const int WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN = 0x00AB;
        const int WM_NCXBUTTONUP = 0x00AC;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
        const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
        const int WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;
        const int WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208;
        const int WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B;
        const int WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C;

        // The Messages array must be sorted due to use of Array.BinarySearch
        static int[] Messages = new int[] {WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,
            WM_NCLBUTTONUP, WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCRBUTTONUP, WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN,
            WM_NCMBUTTONUP, WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCXBUTTONUP, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP,
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_RBUTTONUP,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN, WM_MBUTTONUP, WM_XBUTTONDOWN, WM_XBUTTONUP};

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)  // mouse move is high volume
                return false;
            if (!Program.IdleTimer.Enabled)     // idling?
                return false;           // No
            if (Array.BinarySearch(Messages, m.Msg) >= 0)
                Program.IdleTimer.Stop();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help from you guys.

Comment: Did you try running this application on a computer with touch screen monitor? Did you face any issue ?

Comment: If you have your touchscreen set up to emulate a mouse, I don't see why anything needs to change...

Comment: I tried. It does not work. :-/

Comment: I was hoping the links on the website would be clickable with this approach